# How can I use one algorithm with audit logging and without, without duplication

Tags: java, code-duplication

I have this method. It is a simple example, a synthetic example:

```
 private int foo() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            result += 10;
        } else {
            result += 20;
        }
        builder.append(i).append(" result: ").append(result).append("\n");
    }

    sentToAudit(builder.toString());

    return result;
}
```

As you can see there is a coupling. In one case I need to calculate the result in the loop and just return it. In another case, I need to calculate the result in the loop, return it **and also write to audit.**

I need to separate that method into 2 methods:

```
private int foo1() {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                result += 10;
            } else {
                result += 20;
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }

    private int foo2() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                result += 10;
            } else {
                result += 20;
            }
            builder.append(i).append(" result: ").append(result).append("\n");
        }

        sentToAudit(builder.toString());

        return result;
    }
```

I don't want to do that loop duplication. How can I change this code respecting the SRP and clean code?

Comment: how about a flag passed as parameter to indicate if you want to sent to audit or not? (of case you get the small overhead if an if-condition within the loop.

Comment: @MrSmith42 no, a flag is worst than 2 different methods

Comment: What about a "Dummy" that replaces the StringBuilder in the case you do not want to sent to audit (it would simply have "do-nothing" .append() methods and you would have to handle null or empty in `sentToAudit(...)`

Comment: Why is a flag worse than two methods?

Comment: @ MrSmith42 Because two methods like `calculateAndAudit()` and `calculate()` are more readable than `calculate(true/false)`. When you pass a flag to the method and use this flag in different places of that method, it becames too complicated and dirty.

Comment: You could do both: Make the public-facing methods `calculate()` and `calculateAndAudit()`, but let them call into a single private helper method to avoid code duplication. I'm not a fan of using an `if` condition on a flag: I generally prefer object-oriented approaches rather than code branching. But if it's just a private helper at least it would be relatively small and isolated.

Answer (score 1):

A few options come to mind:

1. Inject an audit logger interface, either into your class constructor or as a method parameter. Have your method call the sendToAudit method on that injected service always. When you don't need to capture the audit information, inject a concrete implementation which doesn't emit audit information.
2. Similar to #1, but make the service you inject be conceptually a publish/subscribe type of event management service. Publish an event indicating what just happened. If audits need to be logged when that particular even happens, have another class subscribe to that event type and log to the audit trail whenever it happens. If not, the event can just be ignored.
3. Make your method return an object that includes both the `result` number *and* the information which may be interesting to log. Have the caller log the information if the situation merits it, or just use the result when it doesn't.
4. Break up the responsibilities further. One method returns a list/stream of cumulative result values. One calling method can get that list/stream and simply capture the last value to use it. Another calling method can use that list/stream to build an audit string and output it, and then optionally still use the last value.

Comment: Yes, I thought about the 3-rd option. It looks better than others.

Comment: @PavelPetrashov: After thinking about it for a bit, I added a fourth option, which is more composition-oriented.